# Spring + Jackson + Deserializing List of Generic Objects

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/inst/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseDTO<InstDTO> 
        testPostREST(@RequestBody RequestDTO<InstDTO> instDTO) {

    RequestDTO<InstDTO> dto = new RequestDTO<InstDTO>();

    ResponseDTO<InstDTO> responseDto = new ResponseDTO<InstDTO>();
    responseDto.setPayload(instDTO.getPayload());
    return responseDto; 
}
```

with the following request object:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class RequestDTO<T> {

    private List<T> payload;

    public RequestDTO() {
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }

    public RequestDTO(List<T> payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public List<T> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(List<T> payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

When the POST comes through and I look the object I get, the payload list has LinkedHashMap objects instead of objects of my DTO type.

How can I make spring+jackson convert the JSON into my DTO object. Bear in mind that I plan to reuse the wrapper ResponseDTO for other lists of objects and that's why I'm using a generic list (List).

Here's the JSON I'm trying.

```
{
  "payload": [
    {
      "d": "Test 0",
      "id": "abcde",
      "c": "Test 0"
    },
    {
      "d": "Test 1",
      "id": "123",
      "c": "Test 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What Spring version are you using?

Comment: I believe this will work out of the box with Spring 3.1+.

Comment: What if I can't upgrade to 3.1? I know the upgrade sounds trivial but it's something out of my control.

Comment: The answer below seems appropriate.

Comment: I was able to do an upgrade after all. I had to go up to Spring 3.2 for it to work and also upgrade Jackson from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2. Seems to be working now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hi, Just wanted to let you know I posted a new question related to this, in case you have time to take a look. It's at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867545/spring-upgrade-tomcat-vs-junit-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work due to type erasure.  Jackson runtime does not know that you are trying to marshal the payload into `InstitutionDTO` objects (since this information has been erased at compile time).  When Jackson looks at the payload, it sees valid JSON objects on the wire and a `List<Object>` on the Java side.  It has no choice but to map the payload to a `Map` implementation, which in your case seems to be `LinkedHashMap`.

You may be able to achieve what you are looking for as follows:

```
class RequestDTO<T> {}
class ResponseDTO<T> {}
class InstitutionDTO {}
class InstitutionRequestDTO extends RequestDTO<InstitutionDTO>
class InstitutionResponseDTO extends ResponseDTO<InstitutionDTO>

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/institution/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody InstitutionResponseDTO
    testPostREST(@RequestBody InstitutionRequestDTO institutionDTO) { }
```

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tried this code myself but most of my applications have code similar to this and it works with Jackson, Castor, Atom, etc. without a glitch.

Comment: Given a method declared as `method(List<String> whatever)`, you can get the generic type argument for `List`. Newer versions of Spring utilize this.

Comment: My attempt was to save the upgrade effort for the poster.

Comment: Your solution is fine, but the statement `Your code does not work due to type erasure` is half correct.

Comment: Thank you both. @Sotirios Could you elaborate on your comment above about getting the generic type argument.

Comment: Manish, what worries me is that I'll end up having to create a XYZRequestDTO for every object I want to use on my Rest services, which seems to be like a lot of overhead. What do you think about that?

Comment: Yes, I agree that you will have to write request and response DTO classes for every use case involving generics.  Unfortunately, there is no other solution given your application set up.

Comment: @jarz Given the `Method` object for a method like `method(List<String> whatever)`, you can get the `String` type argument with `((ParameterizedType)method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]`. Spring 3.1+ does something similar to make code like yours work directly.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by upgrading to spring 3.2. However, when I run my JUnit tests, it behaves like it was before the upgrade. Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If using Jackson isn't a requirement then you might want to consider using Gson instead.

You can tell Gson how to deserialize your json by just passing it a json string and the class that you want to deserialize. It would be pretty simple. I've included an example where I had to deserialize a response from a rest api below.

```
entity = response.getEntity();
jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonResponse).get("result");
returnedProduct = gson.fromJson(root.toString(),Product.class);
```

Comment: This solution could be implemented with Jackson as well.  The poster is not using Jackson directly, but via Spring MVC.  The trouble is how Spring MVC is passing data to Jackson.